# Use same domain for two different subdomains?

Tags: web, dns, subdomain

I have a website called `example.com`.

I want `www.example.com` to point to my blog (on WordPress), but I want `app.example.com` to point to my app (on Heroku).

I am registered with Godaddy (could be any service though).

Is it possible to have one domain go to two completely different places?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is, just create two dns records for example:

www.example.com CNAME hosting.example.com

app.example.com A 109.23.23.45

cheers